# Django - annotate query for if queried user is followed by current user

Tags: python, django

So I have this code below that given a `user_uuid` I look up the info of a user. All `request` come with a auth token that contains the current user's uuid. If the current user queried for their own profile then the `is_current_user` key should be true, which is done with the `item['is_current_user'] = user_uuid == request.user.uuid` line and then I have another flag for if the current user is following the queried user which is `item['is_following'] = FollowUser.objects.filter(follower=str(request.user.uuid), followee=user_uuid).exists()`. As you can see these are very ugly hacks and I was wondering if I could add these values to the `annotate` function.

```
def get_user_info(request, user_uuid):
    try:
        query_annotated = User.objects.annotate(
            follower_count=Count('followee_id', distinct=True),
            followee_count=Count('follower_id', distinct=True)).get(pk=user_uuid)
    except User.DoesNotExist as e:
        return Response(dict(error=str(e),
                             user_message='User not found.'),
                        status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    serializer = FullUserSerializer(query_annotated)
    # TODO: This is a hack the above annotation is not working
    item = serializer.data
    item['is_following'] = FollowUser.objects.filter(follower=str(request.user.uuid), followee=user_uuid).exists()
    item['is_current_user'] = user_uuid == request.user.uuid
    return Response(item, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Version 2**

FullUserSerializer.py

```
class FullUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    follower_count = serializers.IntegerField()
    followee_count = serializers.IntegerField()
    is_following = serializers.BooleanField()
    is_current_user = serializers.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('uuid', 'username', 'avatar', 'created', 'follower_count',
                  'followee_count', 'is_current_user', 'is_following')
```

view.py

```
def get_user_info(request, user_uuid):
    try:
        query_annotated = User.objects.annotate(
            follower_count=Count('followee_id', distinct=True),
            followee_count=Count('follower_id', distinct=True),
            is_following=Exists(
                FollowUser.objects.filter(
                    follower=str(request.user.uuid),
                    followee=OuterRef("pk")
                )
            ),
            is_current_user=Case(
                When(
                    pk=str(request.user.uuid),
                    then=Value(True)
                ),
                default=Value(False),
                output_field=BooleanField(),
            ),
        ).get(pk=user_uuid),
    except User.DoesNotExist as e:
        return Response(dict(error=str(e),
                             user_message='User not found.'),
                        status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    serializer = FullUserSerializer(query_annotated)
    # TODO: This is a hack the above annotation is not working
    # item = serializer.data
    # item['is_following'] = FollowUser.objects.filter(follower=str(request.user.uuid), followee=user_uuid).exists()
    # item['is_current_user'] = user_uuid == request.user.uuid
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

model.py

```
class User(AbstractDatesModel):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=USERNAME_MAX_LEN, unique=True, validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(USERNAME_MIN_LEN)])
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatar_directory_path, blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def avatar_url(self):
        return self.avatar.url
```

Comment: Doesn't look like too much of an "ugly hack" to me.

Comment: @DMalan really? Feel like pulling out serializer.data then modifying it and returning it in the response is unintended by Django design. Also it's better to have consistency across the code i.e. I have all the should be returned params in FullUserSerializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from django.db.models import Case, Exists, OuterRef, When, Value


query_annotated = User.objects.annotate(
    # ...
    is_following=Exists(
        FollowUser.objects.filter(
            follower=str(request.user.uuid), 
            followee=OuterRef("pk")
        )
    ),
    is_current_user=Case(
        When(
            pk=request.user.uuid, 
            then=Value(True)
        ),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    ),
).get(pk=user_uuid)
```

Comment: what's OuterRef() do?

Comment: I got this error `AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `uuid` on serializer `FullUserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `tuple` instance.
Original exception text was: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'uuid'.`

Comment: Can you share your `User` model? The error is because `FullUserSerializer` was configured with a `uuid` field, but it seems the `User` model doesn't have a `uuid` field

Comment: added User model

Comment: Remove the comma at the end of this line: `).get(pk=user_uuid),`. It should just be `).get(pk=user_uuid)`

Comment: apologies I would have given you the bounty but I had a personal crisis these past few days and was not activate on SO. I could have sworn you could give the bounty before even after the expiration, but it's not allowing me the option.

Comment: Dont worry about it. Hope everything is good now